# MySQL- How to fetch occurrence in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

i have data in MySQL table as

[image]

i want to fetch employee records occurrence as shown below

[image]

Sample DATA:

```
CREATE TABLE `login_details` (
  `idlogin_details` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `emp_id` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idlogin_details`)
)

INSERT INTO `login_details` VALUES (1,'3','2018-07-11 05:18:59'),(2,'2','2018-07-11 05:18:59'),(3,'4','2018-07-11 05:18:59'),(4,'1','2018-07-11 05:18:59'),(5,'1','2018-07-13 05:18:59'),(6,'2','2018-07-13 05:18:59'),(7,'3','2018-07-12 05:18:59'),(8,'3','2018-07-13 05:18:59'),(9,'4','2018-07-13 05:18:59'),(10,'5','2018-07-13 05:18:59');
```

Comment: use order by properly

Comment: Upvoted +1.  Generally, adding screen captures of tables is not desirable, but this works with the create and insert statements.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen :  i usually use sqlfiddle.com, but it's down now. So thought of doing this way. Today i got to know that we can use rextester.com also. Thanks.

Comment: @harish_sng ... and Rextester is also sometimes down, in which case I also use Fiddle.  Good to have several options :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if you intend for that `occurrence` column to appear in the result set.  Assuming you don't, you just need an `ORDER BY` clause.  Assuming you *do*, then we have to do more work.  One simple approach is to use a correlated subquery to find the occurrence number:

```
SELECT
    idlogin_details,
    emp_id,
    date,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM login_details t2
     WHERE t1.emp_id = t2.emp_id AND t2.date <= t1.date) occurrence
FROM login_details t1
ORDER BY
    emp_id, date;
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: Prepared [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qJCZxmwU7a163YbXCnySQZ/0) i guess you could use it

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid Thank you.  I was already working on a test demo when you commented :-)